# how to replace a single value in a file using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to replace a value of 528.8933 to -9999 in my file

```
conne <- file("C:\\PHD\\72005ready\\latitude\\latitudefloat.bin", "rb")
   a<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=360*720, signed=F)  
           a[a == 528.8933] <- -9999
```

I used the code give above.But when I checked the results have not been canged.
Any help please

---

EDIT:

The problem has not been solved.I will make it more clear. I am trying to replace a value of 528.8933 to -9999 in my file:

```
        t<- file("C:\\Users\\Amin\\Desktop\\1999n_Resample11.img",    "rb")
           e=readBin(t, double(), size=4,n=720*360, signed=TRUE)
          e[e != -9999] <- e[e != -9999]*0.0099 + 77.65 -273.15
```

This code given above would read a binary file . Then It would do some calculations to e. That worked well. I opened the file again in order to look at the results and I found weird numbers ( 528.8933).

I then used this line :

```
e[e == 528.8933] <- -9999
```

to replace the value of 528.8933  by -9999. I got no errors but when I looked again at the values, I found them as they were(528.8933 is still there) . Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you save the object `a` again? R doesn't make the changes in the file, but in the memory.

Comment: IN fact.I just typed a and viewed the results and they were the same.how can i save it again? please

Comment: Try sum(a == 528.8933) to see how many values R detects. If that's 0, check the type and the values. Are they rounded? To save again, check ?writeBin and the examples

Comment: I am very sure about the type. but yes sum(a== 528.8933) gave
[1] 0    what does that mean?

Comment: That means you read in your values the wrong way. See my answer

Comment: I restored the original question. If you want to add extra information, please add it to the question as to not confuse the readers of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, first : You read in the wrong type. Your values are not integer, as they contain fractional numbers. So you have to read in using `numeric()` instead of `integer()`. Note that this makes really a big difference!

To write your data again, you need `writeBin()`, but again, make sure your type is correct!

A trivial example :

Let's make a file with integers :

```
a <- 1:10

myConn <- file('testBin.bin',open='wb')
writeBin(a,myConn)
close(myConn)
```

You can read this in again like you did:

```
myConn <- file('testBin.bin',open='rb')
x <- readBin(myConn,integer(),n=10)
close(myConn)
```

Now you can change a value. Note that by doing this, you change the type from `integer` to `numeric`!

```
> is.integer(x)
[1] TRUE
> x[x==5] <- 10
> is.integer(x)
[1] FALSE
```

You can save that again as before :

```
myConn <- file('testBin2.bin',open='wb')
writeBin(x,myConn)
close(myConn)
```

And now the important part. If you try to read this file in using `integer()`, you get this:

```
> myConn <- file('testBin2.bin',open='rb')
> X <- readBin(myConn,integer(),n=10)
> close(myConn)
> X
 [1]          0 1072693248          0 1073741824          0 1074266112
 [7]          0 1074790400          0 1076101120
```

That's what you do wrong. Check your values in `a`, they won't be what you expect them to be. So you need to use `numeric()` as type :

```
> myConn <- file('testBin2.bin',open='rb')
> X <- readBin(myConn,numeric(),n=10)
> close(myConn)
> X
 [1]  1  2  3  4 10  6  7  8  9 10
```

Read also the help file `?readBin` very carefully.

---

**Answer to your edit:**

The problem you talk about in your edit seems to be twofold:

1. You don't use the right type for reading the corrected binary file. Check that using eg `class(e)` after you did the calculations. Probably that tells you `numeric` instead of `double`
2. You expect that the printed value `528.8933` is exactly that value. It is not, it is printed rounded but the true value is something else. Hence your comparison `e == 528.8933` doesn't return anything, as the true value would be eg `528.8933452...`.

To get around that, try:

```
round(e,4) == 528.8933
```

instead.

Comment: PS : use `unlink('testBin.bin')` and `unlink('testBin2.bin')` to clean up your working directory